# How to build a chrome extension to highlight text on a specific URl

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am relatively new to both programming and developing chrome extensions. I am developing a chrome extension that will do this simple  thing.

1. On selecting a text, show a button on clicking which the text will be highlighted. (Somewhat like the pin button)
2. When i revisit the page I can see what where the areas i highlighted.

So currently I have a extension working which can save the bookmark to the database. This is the link from which i got this understanding http://markashleybell.com/building-a-simple-google-chrome-extension.html. If you want i can share the actual code also but it is going to crowd the question.

I think I can make get the selected text to go in to the database if i use contextmenus. But this is what i intend to do is

1. select the text
2. A icon comes up (H**ow do i trigger the jquery to add the button, which chrome api i need to use and in which file i should put the code)**
   3 On clicking the icon the text gets highlighted. (**how should i change the DOM of the current page)**

I can do the part of extracting the text and sending it to the Database.

The next problem i have no idea about what information I need to store in the database (Example do i need to store the start or end node) so that i can have the text highlighted when i return to the URl. **How does a chrome extension start on its own to figure out what part of the page need to be highlighted.**

In case you have a sample code that will be great or just tell me what is the logic and chrome api's i need to use.

I know the question is too broad but even if you have a few links that can help to understand this flow it will be great. **The project i am working on it to create a far similar version of https://www.diigo.com/, with just the ability to store URL along with the highlighted notes.**

Comment: I do believe this question is too broad in scope. Take a look at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide; you may need to break up this question in parts, and make sure to include what your current understanding is (what did you research, what did you try)

Comment: I have made some additions to the question to further clarify what i am trying to do. This is my first time coding a chrome extension so i am basically on ground zero.  http://markashleybell.com/building-a-simple-google-chrome-extension.html. I have build the base of my extension using this link.

Comment: You did improve the question a lot, thanks for the effort.

Comment: Your problem is, however, unsolvable in general. There is no guarantee that the structure of the document will be the same when you load it, even if the URL matches.

Comment: But there are chrome extension that do it, you can check out diigo.  It may fail on a few pages but it should work in general, And i honestly have more than one problem in general, some of them should be solvable

Comment: Then you need to be more specific in what you want to re-highlight. Set up rules that survive the change of structure. What factors are you going to look for to find the "same" place?

Comment: Sorry but its still too broad. Most of your issues are not related to chrome extensions but are html/dom questions. Instead try to solve each and show what problems you are having with your code. show the code. Regarding how to remember a position in the dom, look at it like a tree and remember where in that structure is your start/end.

Comment: @ZigMandel Sorry if the question is too broad, I will take your advice and start coding the whole thing and ask questions along the way. Can you just tell me just how the Pin it button appear when you hover over a image. I just need to know what listener i need to configure to execute  the button through jquery

Comment: @Xan- I am not too clear about how i will do it. I am just clear about what i want to create. For example, I like your comment so i highlight it, so when i return to this url I want this selection to be already highlighted. Can you just tell me how do i execute a script from my extension without the user clicking on the extension button.

Comment: I suggest you make another specific question about the pin issue. Its unrelated to extensions. Its just a regular html/dom question.

Comment: @Zig Mandel  Guys I have made a specific question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052171/unable-to-interact-with-the-dom-of-the-page-while-build-a-chrome-extension I have started to execute the project and i am addressing each problem as it comes.

Comment: @xan  I have made a specific question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052171/unable-to-interact-with-the-dom-of-the-page-while-build-a-chrome-extension I have started to execute the project and i am addressing each problem as it comes. can you help me with this