# Unable to interact with the DOM of the page while building a chrome extension

Tags: jquery, dom, google-chrome-extension

Guys i am trying to create something like this.
https://www.uploady.com/#!/download/3FQNqMKaxCu/WnMhnfYaXKXRSTVv Or you can imagine a "Pin it" kind of button incase if any text is highlighted.

I am sorry if my problem might seem small, but i have just started programming.

I am unable to make the code in my content scripts work. Can some one point out where I might be going wrong.

here is the code i am trying to execute. **I want to launch a alert box on any webpage whenever i select any text**. Later I will replace it the actual button like in the image. here is the code

myscript.js

```
    function getSelectedText()
    {
        var txt = '';
         if (window.getSelection)
        {
            txt = window.getSelection();
                 }
        else if (document.getSelection)
        {
            txt = document.getSelection();
                }
        else(document.selection)
        {
            txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
                }
    return txt;

    }


      $('window').mouseup(function() {
        var text=getSelectedText();
        if (text!='') alert(text);

    });
```

Here is my manifest.json file

```
// JavaScript Document

    {    
        "manifest_version": 2,
        "name":"knowledge maps extension",
        "version":"1.0",
        "description":"",
        "browser_action":{ 
        "default_icon":"logo1.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
                },

        "background":{
        "scripts":["background.js"],

       "persistent": false},


        "permissions": [ "tabs","http://*/*", "https://*/*" , "contextMenus"],

         "web_accessible_resources": [ "jquery-1.10.1.min.map", "frame.html" ],
     "homepage_url": "http://localhost/trial/Untitled-1.php",

     "content_scripts": [ {
      "js": [ "jquery-1.10.1.min.js","myscript.js"],      
      "css": ["mystyles.css"],

      "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
   } ]

   }
```

can someone point out if i am in the right direction. I think if i can have the alert to go off, i can easily replace it by adding a button using jquery. I want to keep my code simple so i am addressing on problem at a time

Comment: Have you tried looking in the console for errors?

Comment: Why run at document start? That could cause issues, remove it

Comment: I have no clue how to find the console, but i will start looking into it. Do you find the code to be correct

Comment: @pavneettiwana Take a look at [Dev Tools overview](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) and this little [extension debugging tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging).

Comment: @ZigMandel i tried doing that it doesn't work. I think either my permissions are incorrect or i need to execute myscript.js from some other file. i want it to launch a popup everytime i select some text. I have made the changes to the code to show you

Comment: It's usually considered poor form to edit your question to make an existing answer incorrect.  You now have several possible ways to make your extension work.  Good luck.

Comment: @Teepeemm I just edited to the question to let XAN and ZIG know that i have implemented there recommendations. I didn't wanted to make a existing answer incorrent. Sorry new to stackoverflow, sorry if i did something wrong

Comment: @ZigMandel thanks for the help it. Extension is working, the popup is appearing now.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't wrap code in `<script>` tags: Chrome expects a JS source file, not an HTML snippet.

Please debug your code: look in the console and Dev Tools in general.

Comment: Xan thanks for the input, i checked the console it is saying syntax error, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: @pavneettiwana Since your code does not deal with styles, it must come from jQuery; Zig Mandel is correct, there may be problems from running at `document_start`.

Comment: thanks for your help, the first problem is solved, know off to the next one. The console thing really helped.